# Windows 8 hostednetwork and ICS issue, no internet access

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

### The Issue

Trying to host a network to extend the range of my home wifi network, instead of going out and spending 50 bucks on a wifi extender.

Anyways my issue occurs in that my hostednetwork does not have internet access no matter what I've tried.

---

### What I've done

#### Setting up

First things first, I started by starting up ICS first, as I need the DHCP server to assign IP's in the range of 192.168.137.x on my to be hostednetwork.

I then set up a hostednetwork via command line like so:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid="Test" key="password"
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

It works fine, I was able to test this connection by syncing my phones music collection 'over wifi' (DoubleTwist AirSync).  I state this because I had originally started my hostednetwork first, which starts ICS in standalone mode, which then assigns IP's in 192.168.173.x instead, and DoubleTwist could not find my phone.  Though I could've just released and renewed IP's once I had the ICS full mode started.

Anyways next step I took.  I went into to network adapter settings, right clicked my wifi adapter that's connected to my home network and enabled shared internet connection with the newly created hostednetwork.

Nada, nothing happens.

---

### System Information

IPconfig /all:

[image: IPconfig /all]

Network Adapter Settings:

[image: Network Adapter Settings]

---

### End

I have no idea why this isn't working, every guide and support forum I've googled have done exactly what I have and it's worked for them.  I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to share internet from the same adapter as I am broadcasting from. I would love to be able to broadcast from a seperate dongle (I have a spare) but windows doesn't support that natively.

Comment: Same story here. Its set up perfectly but no ip addresses are being assigned to any clients. I tried all the solutions over here: http://superuser.com/q/804227/109803 and none of them work. I am going to try to enable DHCP. B/c in ipconfig /all it says its disabled.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @gabriel fair No, I gave up hahah sorry.

Comment: Yeah I did as well. lol

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Sharing and using hostednetwork can be a stress. This is how i've done it.
Using command line and powershell to achieve needed goals.
Sure it could be achieved with powershell only but hey ... probably later.

Save the following (BATCH FILE) file as a *.bat. Change accordingly where it reads

> YOURPATH\YOURFILE.ps1

Save the second file (PS1 FILE) with name you supplied in previous step

> "YOURFILE.ps1"

Alter the first section of ps1 file and change adapters accordingly with your system

```
$wifi = "description='Broadcom 4313 802.11b/g/n'"
$ethernet = "description='Intel(R) 82577LC Gigabit Network Connection'"
```

You can get yours running the following command in powershell

> Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | select description

**Its supposed to have only one connected interface either physical (ethernet) or wireless.**
Run batch file as administrator.
Additionaly you can start the process from the windows explorer context menu for simplicity.
For that use the third file and save it as a reg and run it or alter manually from the sample
Needless to say that its necessary to alter where it reads

> YOURPATH\BATCHFILE.bat

Enjoy. Cheers

-------------------------------------------- BATCH FILE

```
@echo off
echo Current Settings (netsh wlan show hostednetwork):
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i status
rem echo               Current Settings
rem echo            ######################
rem echo .
echo SSID Name
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i " ssid "
netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security
echo            ######################
echo            #                    #
echo            # Please select      #
echo            #                    #
echo            #   [E] Edit     #
echo            #   [S] Start    #
echo            #   [Q] Stop     #
echo            #   [V] View     #
echo            #                    #
echo            ######################
choice /C ESQV 
IF errorlevel 4 goto TetherView
IF errorlevel 3 goto TetherStop
IF errorlevel 2 goto TetherStart
IF errorlevel 1 goto TetherEdit
rem GOTO TetherEnd

:TetherEdit
echo "Please enter SSID:" 
set /p SSID=
echo "SSID Password"
set /p PassWord=
echo %SSID% %PassWord%
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%SSID% key=%PassWord%
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
GOTO TetherEnd

:TetherStart
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
powershell -file YOURPATH\ICS-Control.ps1 enable
GOTO TetherEnd

:TetherStop
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
powershell -file YOURPATH\ICS-Control.ps1 disable
GOTO TetherEnd

:TetherView
cls
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i status
echo SSID Name
netsh wlan show hostednetwork | findstr -i " ssid "
netsh wlan show hostednetwork setting=security
echo Connected clients
arp -a | findstr -i 192.168.173 | findstr /V 255 | findstr /V 192.168.173.1
GOTO TetherEnd

:TetherEnd
@PAUSE
```

--------------------------------------------PS1 FILE

```
#Change accordingly
$wifi = "description='Broadcom 4313 802.11b/g/n'"
$ethernet = "description='Intel(R) 82577LC Gigabit Network Connection'"

#Doesnt change so no need to alter. Detects what interface is connected (should be only one)
$netAdapter = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | select netconnectionid, name, InterfaceIndex, netconnectionstatus 
if ($netAdapter.netconnectionid -cmatch "Wi-Fi"){$publicAdapter = $wifi} else {$publicAdapter = $ethernet}
$privateAdapter = "description='Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter'"

Function Var1ICSenable
{
    $virtualAdapter = Get-WMIObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where {$_.ServiceName -eq "vwifimp"} | % {$_.GetRelated('win32_networkadapter')} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    $vars1 = $privateAdapter
    $Adapter0 = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter $vars1 | select description
    $mAdapter3 = $Adapter0 -replace "@{description=",""
    $mAdapter3 = $mAdapter3 -replace "}","" 
    $mAdapter4 = "description='$mAdapter3'"
    $mAdapter5 = gwmi win32_networkadapter -Filter $mAdapter4 |select netconnectionid
    $mAdapter5 = $mAdapter5 -replace "@{netconnectionid=",""
    $global:mAdapter5 = $mAdapter5 -replace "}",""
}

Function Var2ICSenable
{
    $vars2 = $publicAdapter
    $Adapter1 = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter $vars2 | select description
    $mAdapter = $Adapter1 -replace "@{description=",""
    $mAdapter = $mAdapter -replace "}","" 
    $mAdapter1 = "description='$mAdapter'"
    $mAdapter2 = gwmi win32_networkadapter -Filter $mAdapter1 |select netconnectionid
    $mAdapter2 = $mAdapter2 -replace "@{netconnectionid=",""
    $global:mAdapter2 = $mAdapter2 -replace "}",""
}

function EnableDisableICS
{

    $bFound = $FALSE

    $oNetSharingManager = new-object -comobject HNetCfg.HNetShare
     if ($oNetSharingManager -eq $null)
        {
            write-host "Unable to get the HNetCfg.HnetShare object."
            Exit
        }    
    if ($oNetSharingManager.SharingInstalled -eq $null)
        {
            write-host "Sharing is not available on this platform."
            Exit
        }

    $oConnectionCollection = $oNetSharingManager.EnumEveryConnection
    foreach ($oItem In $oConnectionCollection)
    {
        $EveryConnection = $oNetSharingManager.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($oItem)
        $objNCProps = $oNetSharingManager.NetConnectionProps($oItem)
        If ($objNCProps.name -eq $sPrivateConnectionName)
        {
            $bFound = $True
            write-host "Setting ICS Private to " $bEnable " on connection: " $objNCProps.name
            If ($bEnable -eq "true")
                {
                    $EveryConnection.EnableSharing(1)
                }
            Else
                {
                    $EveryConnection.DisableSharing()
                }
        }
    }

    $oConnectionCollection = $oNetSharingManager.EnumEveryConnection
    foreach ($oItem In $oConnectionCollection)
    {
        $EveryConnection = $oNetSharingManager.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection($oItem)
        $objNCProps = $oNetSharingManager.NetConnectionProps($oItem)

        If ($objNCProps.name -eq $sPublicConnectionName)
        {
           $bFound = $True
           write-host "Setting ICS Public to " $bEnable " on connection: " $objNCProps.name
            If ($bEnable -eq "true")
            {
                $EveryConnection.EnableSharing(0)
            }
            Else
            {
                $EveryConnection.DisableSharing()
            }
        }
    }

    If ($bFound -eq $null)
    {
       write-host "Unable to find the connection " + $sPublicConnectionName
    }

}

Function EnableSharing
{
    #regsvr32 /s hnetcfg.dll

        # Variables to enable and disable ICS
        Var1ICSenable
        Var2ICSenable
        $global:firstICSvar = $global:mAdapter2
        $global:secondICSvar = $global:mAdapter5

    $benable = "true"
    $sPublicConnectionName = $global:firstICSvar
    $sPrivateConnectionName = $global:secondICSvar

    $mstr = $sPublicConnectionName + " " + $sPrivateConnectionName + " " + $bEnable
    EnableDisableICS $mstr
}

Function DisableSharing
{
    #regsvr32 /s hnetcfg.dll

        # Variables to enable and disable ICS
        Var1ICSenable
        Var2ICSenable
        $global:firstICSvar = $global:mAdapter2
        $global:secondICSvar = $global:mAdapter5

    $benable = "false"
    $sPublicConnectionName = $global:firstICSvar
    $sPrivateConnectionName = $global:secondICSvar

    $mstr = $sPublicConnectionName + " " + $sPrivateConnectionName + " " + $bEnable
    EnableDisableICS $mstr
    #write-host "TESTE" $mstr
}

    if ($args[0] -eq "enable"){EnableSharing}else{DisableSharing}
```

--------------------------------------------REG FILE

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas]
@="Tether (Hosted Network)"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /c YOURPATH\BATCHFILE.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this post is so high in the search I'll repeat myself here, maybe it helps.

1. As mentioned in several posts I've enabled the routing and remoting service.

but that was only part of the solution, the internet still didn't work. So when checking the hosted wireless adapter settings I noticed that the IP Address was static but there wasn't any DNS Server entry. So here comes part 2 of the solution.

2. Edit hosted network IPv4 Settings. Enter a valid DNS Server (Use any open dns server available, e.g. google's is 8.8.8.8)

That worked for me.

Comment: You added this to your "Microsoft hosted network virtual adapter" connection correct? It did not work for me.

Comment: For me to get a DNS entry, I had to do this: see this answer: http://superuser.com/a/1051122/35525

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the internet connection that you are using on your computer. You need to go to Network Center and then to Adapter Settings. Then right-click the connection you want to share, then click properties and go to the share tab. There you need to share with your hostednetwork.

Comment: Which is what I have done.

Comment: Scratch that apparently it has been working.  Windows says there's internet connectivity on it.  My phone just doesn't think there is.

Comment: I'm sorry I read it too fast. It's a whole other problem if your phone  doens't see the connection. What kind of phone do you have? If have encountered some problems as well. My phone can't connect to my network.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a little late for you and maybe you've already bought a wifi extender or something. However I'm extending my wifi signal just the way you were trying and didn't succeed at first but then i used the command line without the "" marks, and now everything is working just fine. I've tried some more things which might possibly influence the process, but i can't exactly remember them.

Comment: I gave up on it actually.  It was all working fine actually, just for whatever reason my Nexus 4 doesn't like using the shared internet.  But I do know internet was being shared correctly, I was able to connect to it via a laptop.